# Sculpting Viewport Shading

Tags: sculpt

Please forgive such a basic question but I'm very confused - my viewport shading in Sculpt mode is gray, instead of that nice red colour. I'm sure it always used to default to the red. I've restored the factory defaults, I've reset the preferences to factory defaults and I deleted the startup file under User/AppData/Roaming...etc. Nothing has worked. How can I restore the default behaviour, or have I overlooked something silly?

I'm using version 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just have your viewport shading set to something else. It varies by each individual 3D View window as well.

Click on the little icon as indicated. You will find the red material you're looking for in the matcaps section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rekov. I realize I can set this manually each time but how can I set this as the default material in Sculpt Mode? I'm sure it always used to work that way.

Comment: Are you going into sculpt mode by clicking on the sculpting tab at the top? https://i.imgur.com/KREcO2i.png If you don't have a sculpting tab you can add it by clicking the little + icon instead. This is the 'correct' way to get the sculpting layout in 2.8, as opposed to picking sculpt mode from the drop-down. The sculpting tab should already have the matcap set as default. If it isn't, set it so in a new file, and save that as your start-up file (File > Defaults > Save Startup)

Comment: Yes I was using the tab to get in to sculpt mode, also tried File > New > Sculpting. I just changed the matcap manually and saved the startup file and all seems to be working OK now. Still not sure why resetting all the factory defaults didn't work but I won't worry too much about it for now.